# c - using a pointer returned from function in a function call

Tags: c, mongodb, memory-management

Is the following usage of pointers in functions call is a memory leak:

```
bson_t * parse_json(const char * json_fields){

    bson_error_t error;
    bson_t *bson_fields = bson_new_from_json((unsigned char *)json_fields, -1, &error);
    if (!bson_fields) {
        log_die("Error: %s\n", error.message);
    } else {
      return bson_fields;
    }
    log_die("Error: something bad happend in parse_columns");
    return bson_fields; // this should never be reached ...
}
```

The following code works, but what happens to the pointer from `parse_json` here? Is this a memory leak?

```
bson_concat(fields, parse_json(json_fields));
```

The mongodb C-API offers the function `bson_destory`:

```
bson_destroy(fields);
```

I am wondering maybe it's better to explicitly free the memory of `new_fields`:

```
        bson_t *new_fields = parse_json(json_fields);
        bson_concat(fields, new_fields);
        bson_destroy(new_fields);
```

While this example uses mongodb c-api, I am also trying to understand the general case.

```
  some_type * pointer_returner(){
  some_type *var;
  ...

  return var;
  }


  do_something(pointer_retuner());
```

Is the call above causing a memory leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to call `bson_destroy` to deallocate your structure object it is no longer used.

From `bson_destroy` [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_destroy.html):

> The bson_destroy() function shall free an allocated bson_t structure.
>
> This function should always be called when you are done with a bson_t unless otherwise specified.

Comment: so the snippet which declared the variable `new_fields` is the correct way. But do I always need to release a pointer returned from function when used in the call for another function?

Comment: @Oz123 you need to deallocate it when you now longer use it.

Comment: @Oz123 in the new case you show you'll have a leak if you don't deallocate in `do_something` as otherwise the pointer value will be lost and you won't able to deallocate it later.

Comment: AH! Great, thanks for confirming my thoughts. I think you should add your comment to your answer.